2021 Community Moderator Election Results
Moderator election #1 on Psychology & Neuroscience has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:




They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results here or view a summary report online.

Welcome @BryanKrause! And, thank you for years of great work, Jeromy!

Many thanks moderators for your professionalism and dedication to the forum.

Congratulations to the mods. Some questions: how do we assess the diversity of the site? Do we have the diversity we need yet? Do the mod team need to be diverse too to maintain the diversity of the community?
